# Why doesn't my regular expression work with Perl's Switch module?

Tags: perl, switch-statement

I wanted to use a switch statement. I ran into difficulties quickly. It looks like I was unlucky. I decided to use if else style instread of the switch.

I wonder why this does not work. What about you? It looks like there is problem with /gc flags on the regular expression.

```
use Switch;
while ( pos($file) < length($file) ) {
   switch ($file)
   {

   case  (/\G\s*object\s+(\w+)\s*\:\s*(\w+)/gc)  {
   }
   }
   last if ( $oldpos == pos($file) );
   $oldpos = pos($file);
 }
```

It was suggested that something like case  (m!\G\s*object\s+(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)!gc)   would work. It does not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Switch.pm is implemented with source filters, which can lead to strange bugs which are very hard to track down. I don't recommend the use of Switch in production code because of its unpredictability. The Switch.pm docs also [mention](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Switch-2.14/Switch.pm#LIMITATIONS) that it can have trouble parsing regexes with modifiers.

If you're using Perl 5.10, you can use the new built-in [`given/when`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements) syntax instead.

```
use feature 'switch';
given ( $file ) { 
    when ( /\G\s*object\s+(\w+)\s*\:\s*(\w+)/gc ) { 
        ...
    }
}
```

If you're using pre-5.10, the best thing is probably to use an `if/else` structure.

Comment: I also believe that the Switch module will be deprecated in 5.10.1 and removed in 5.12.

Comment: It also doesn't set `$_`, like it should.

Answer (score 6):

Please have a look at the ["Limitations" section of the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html#LIMITATIONS). It's suggested that you use regexes of the form "m? ... ?" to overcome some parsing problems. That may work for you.

Alternatively, have a look at the [perlsyn(1)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements) section on switch statements:

> Switch statements
>
> ```
>   Starting from Perl 5.10, you can say
>
>       use feature "switch";
>
>   which enables a switch feature that is closely based on the Perl 6
>   proposal.
>
>   The keywords "given" and "when" are analogous to "switch" and "case" in
>   other languages, so the code above could be written as
>
>       given($_) {
>           when (/^abc/) { $abc = 1; }
>           when (/^def/) { $def = 1; }
>           when (/^xyz/) { $xyz = 1; }
>           default { $nothing = 1; }
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 5):

The documentation I found on the web ([here](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html)) seems to imply you  can't use additiononal modifiers on your regex.

Your code, sans the /gc, compiled and ran for me .. (but makes no sense .. since pos doesn't do what is needed!

*PLEASE*

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

then provide a second sample with $file initialized .

**EDIT:** Take a look at Friedo's and Inshalla's suggestion of using Perl 5.10's "given - when" construct! That's the way to go!

Comment: Seriously, everyone, use warnings; use strict;  It really will save you a lot of pain.